# Need syncing cloud storage that works across Linux, Windows, some Android

Tags: android, sync, cloud, dropbox, latex

Until recently, I used Dropbox as my cloud storage, which worked awesome across Windows, Android, and Ubuntu, where I saved all my research and could access pretty much anywhere. But now Dropbox for some weird reason has stopped supporting Linux, and what this means in practice is that it no longer works on my school computer, it no longer syncs to my "offline" folder.

Ideally, I either need to fix the Dropbox issue (which appears not possible since the Linux computers are school computers for which I don't have administrator access, and the IT people here refuse to help me), or find a suitable replacement. For instance, Google Drive appears to not be a good enough replacement, because there is no easy way for me to sync Google Drive to an "offline" folder in my school storage, since Google Drive does not support Linux either (!). The reason that using Google Drive on the web browser is not good enough for me is that I need to edit the files in my Google Drive through an offline app, when I'm using the school computer (namely, a LaTeX editor).

I will be content with some solution that allows me to

1) Save and edit through offline apps the cloud storage files in Windows and Linux.

2)Access the files in Android.

Please help me solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`dropbox` works for me. I use it to transfer all sorts of files between Linux and Android. To get `dropbox` to keep working for me, I had to move the `Dropbox` folder away from my encrypted `$HOME` directory (`dropbox` recently started complaining about filesystems of type `ecryptfs`, probably because encrypyed `$HOME` directory goes away when I log out).

In preparation, I decided to put `dropbox` files in `/home/Dropbox` (an `ext4` filesystem, always mounted). I did:

```
sudo mkdir --mode=700 /home/Dropbox
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/Dropbox
```

Then, Right-or-Left-Click on the `dropbox` icon in the top right, select `Preferences...`. Once the `Dropbox Preferences` window opens, Right-Click on the `Sync` icon. The bottom part of that screen says `Dropbox folder location`. Enter `/home/Dropbox` and click `Move`.

When that finishes, restart `dropbox`, just to be sure.

```
dropbox stop
dropbox status
dropbox start
dropbox status
```

You should be able to get the IT people to

```
sudo mkdir --parents --mode=700 /home/user/Dropbox
sudo chown user /home/user/Dropbox
```

for you, and use that directory.

If they won't do anything, can you insert a USB key and use the above method to move your Dropbox directory there? Be sure to `dropbox stop;dropbox status` before removing the USB key.